# No GUI when I login to the Enlightment DE (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: 13.04, login, monitor, enlightenment

Ubuntu noob here again. 
I recently installed the desktop environment Enlightenment for Ubuntu 13.04. 
It was running great until now. I think it may have to do something with the monitor I hooked into my laptop. I can login to any other desktop environment just fine without any issues. However, when I login to Enlightenment, I get a black screen with a cursor. I have to hard shutdown every time. How can I fix this? I've tried to login without my monitor plugged in, and it still does the same thing. Maybe I can uninstall it? I do not know the command though, so if that could be one solution, I don't mind. Just please make sure to leave the command to remove Enlightenment in your answer if you don't mind.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The enlightenment version in the official repositories is quite old and buggy. If you need a (more or less)  stable e17,I'd go with the semi-official PPA: 
https://launchpad.net/~efl/+archive/trunk

It might not work, to directly install the PPA packages without first uninstalling e17 (and maybe also all the EFL libs).

To completely get rid of e17, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge e17
```

To also remove libs installed by e17 and not needed by anything else:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

You can also try to reset your e17 settings to defaults. To do this, you can simply remove the hidden folder .e in your home directory.